# Passing String parameter into Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, param

I am passing String parameter into javascript . But it is not being called. this is my script:

```
function downloadPopup(testing){      
alert(testing); }
```

I am calling the javascript like this from my jsp page:

```
<% String testing = "DSfsdsfd" ; %> <a
href="javascript:downloadPopup(<%=testing%>)"
> Click </a>
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing quotes around your string:

```
<% String testing = "DSfsdsfd" ; %> <a
href="javascript:downloadPopup('<%=testing%>')"
> Click </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
downloadPopup('<%=testing%>')
```

dont forget to put string in ''

Comment: This works unless the string itself has quotes in it. Whatever language or web framework you're in probably has a "to_json" method. Call that on the string and it quotes it and escapes the quotes for you.

Comment: You're right darkporter. If the string has quotes in it you'll get a js error. If C# you can escape quotes as follows.
'<%=testing.Replace("'","\\\'") %>'